# What does this sentence mean? Frank’s quote of House of cards

Tags: meaning

Cry havoc those who fight chaos with chaos. And let slip the dog of war.

Could you please explaing the exact meaning of this one?

Answer (score 3):

**cry havoc**. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dogs_of_war_(phrase))

Netflix Series:  *House of Cards*. It is an allusion to a line in the play Julius Caesar by William Shakespeare: "Cry havoc and let slip the dogs of war." "Havoc" was a word used in the middle ages by French & English armies to give soldiers permission to loot & plunder

[dogs of war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dogs_of_war_(phrase))

In a literal reading, "dogs" are the familiar animals, trained for warfare; "havoc" is a military order permitting the seizure of spoil after a victory and "let slip" is to release from the leash.